# Would be great- word use

Tags: word-usage

I want to ask somebody to have a look on my online advertisement.

Is my sentence correct?

Do I use would correctly?

**Would be great if you could have a look on my advertisement**

Or

**Much appreciated if you could have a look on my advertisement**

Comment: It would be better if you started with the word “it”: _It would be great if you could..._ (Leaving off the “it” is acceptable as informal speech, but if you’re truly worried about grammar you might want to include it.)

Comment: **It would be great...** is an informal expression, more likely to be used among friends and colleagues. **It would be appreciated...** is more formal, better suited to a request aimed at teachers, employers and the like.

Comment: Usually one would say "have a look **at** my *(online)* advertisement".

Answer (score 1):

The sentence

> Would be great if you could have a look at my advertisement

elides (omits) the initial "It" which serves as the subject of the verb (to be). This is a judgement call, but I would think this appropriate only for highly informal conversation among friends. If a co-worker said this, asking for input on a business project, I would have a negative view.

I would also say "if you would have a look..." rather than "could" because i am asking if the person is **willing** to do this, not if s/he is **able** to. But that is a nuance that even many native speakers now ignore, and either will be understood.

(I agree with the previous answer that it should be "look **at** my advertisement", not look **on** my advertisement".)

Answer (score 0):

"On" is not the correct preposition. Use "at" instead.

"Would be great if you could have a look at my advertisement" is completely normal english.

"Much appreciated if you could take a look at my advertisement" is also totally acceptable